# Create array class with Search method for const of plain types (int) and pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers, partial-specialization

now i have

```
template<class C> class Array
{
inline int Search(const C &value) const;
...
}
```

i want to use in this way

```
Array<int *> a;
int i;
const int *pi = &i;
a.Search(pi);
```

but i got

> error C2664: 'A::Search' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const
>   int *' to 'int *const &'

is it possible to workaround it somehow?

Only i can think for now it is to partially specialize this claxx for pointers, but i'm not sure.

```
template<class C> class Array<C*>
{
inline int Search(const C *&value) const;
...
}
```

Is it good way, maybe it is possible to do it without creating partial specialization?

Comment: Why don't you use std::vector?

Comment: @Daniel Daranas, Can't use std in my project.

Comment: @Daniel Daranas, i'm not a team lead))

Comment: Well, can you use `boost`? Might as well state all the restrictions of your team, otherwise it will be difficult to give a useful answer.

Comment: Why would a team restrict the use of the STL? I can understand boost as that requires distributing the libraries, but STL is practically built into the language, there is no reason not to use it.

Comment: @juanchopanza, we don't use boost either(, we write library, engine, and may be it is because of perfofmance issues. Please, it is not about STL or boost or something like that.

Comment: @Yola Ah, you use your own containers because the ones in the STL have performance issues, while yours are faster. Ok. I understand. *sigh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, your problem comes from the fact that you're adding a top-level `const` to your template parameter, but when it comes to pointers it yields `T * const` not `T const *`.

Specializing your template is one way to do achieve what you want.

Another way would be to make a helper template that takes care of the deep "constification" and use this in your main template. This is usually easier to do it that way because it means less code duplication. Something along the lines of:

```
template<typename C>
struct Constify {
  typedef const C type;
};

template<typename C>
struct Constify<C*> {
  typedef const C* const type;
};

template<class C>
class Array
{
  inline int Search(typename Constify<C>::type & value) const;
  ...
};
```

Comment: Yet one layer of abstraction may solve any problems)) Thanks, +1